# Series object has no split attribute - reading in data from text file

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in data from a .txt file that looks like the following, and I am extracting the third item in each of the brackets with the code that is at the bottom.

With the line, `data = data.iloc[0, ::4]`, I was removing 3 out of every 4 data points (I think).

However, now I am trying to keep every data points.  So when I remove the line; `data = data.iloc[0, ::4]`, I receive the following error:

`"'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 0'`

I don't understand why removing that line will give me the error that I am receiving.  In short, I would like to extract every third item from each bracket, and store it in a `pandas` `DataFrame`.  But when I try to remove the line, `data = data.iloc[0, ::4]`, I get the error thrown (as shown above).

Thanks for the support!

[image]

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data_test9.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
data = data.iloc[0, ::4]
data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
data.pop(0)
xar = range(len(data)
yar = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Piece of Data:

```
[0.0, -0.01953125, -0.0009765625][0.0, -0.01953125, -0.0009765625][0.0, -0.01953125, -0.0009765625][0.0, -0.01953125, -0.0009765625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.912109375, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.978515625, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.978515625, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.978515625, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.978515625, -0.00390625][0.0087890625, -0.978515625, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9521484375, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.955078125, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0048828125][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0087890625, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.0029296875][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0068359375, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625][0.0078125, -0.9560546875, -0.00390625]
```

**Edit 1:**
My data is being saved as follows:

```
while True:
    delay(DELAY_INTERVAL)

    file = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\demo3.txt", "a")
    file.writelines(str(convert(readField())))
    file.flush()
    file.close()
```

Comment: Fundamentally, you should reconsider the format you are saving the data, which looks like a `print` dump. Use a `csv` format, or something else.

Comment: So, as I suspected you are basiclaly dumping the  `str` representation of a some data-structure to a text file. *Dont do this*. You will have to parse the data back into the data-structure as you are attempting to do. Just use an accepted and supported format, like `csv`. Then you don't have to write parsing logic.

Comment: I am thinking of using `csvwriter`.  Is this a good idea?

Comment: Sure. Are each of these bracketed lists of numbers suppose to be "rows"? Then basically you can probably just use `writer.writerow(convert(readField()))` in a loop.

Comment: And note, `pandas` knows how to read csvs already, so then to get your data in a `pd.DataFrame` you can just use `pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\demo3.txt")`

Comment: Seems to be working more in-line with my expectations.  Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `data` is a `pd.DataFrame`, so when you `.apply` a function to it, it passes a `pd.Series` as the argument to the function. `pd.Series` doesn't have a `.split` method. When you do:

```
data = data.iloc[0, ::4]
```

You are selecting the *first row* and every four columns, starting with the first. This *returns a `pd.Series`. So consider:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
     a   b   c   d   e
0  -10  17  17  14 -10
1    2  10   0   4  -5
2   16  10   1  -9  -6
3   12  -6  10   5   3
4    9  10  -4  10   3
5   -8  16   4  17   0
6    9  12   4  17  -5
7   19  17   9   2  19
8    1   4  10  10  12
9   12  -1   9  -5  10
10  -1  -3   4  11   5
11  19   4   6  16   3
12   5  19  -1   1  15
13  18   2  15   0   7
14   3  10  15   6  15
15   8  12   3  -6   8
16  14   0  -3   6   2
17  -1  -5  -5  -3  16
18  -2  12  17  17  13
19  18   4  19  14   4

In [17]: df.iloc[0, ::4]
Out[17]:
a   -10
e   -10
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [18]: type(df.iloc[0, ::4])
Out[18]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Now, when you `.apply` a function to a *series* it passes each *value* in the series to the function, which is why your `lambda` works, since each value is a `str`, and strings *do have* a `.split` method.

So, perhaps you want:

```
In [19]: df.iloc[::4,:]
Out[19]:
     a   b   c   d   e
0  -10  17  17  14 -10
4    9  10  -4  10   3
8    1   4  10  10  12
12   5  19  -1   1  15
16  14   0  -3   6   2

In [20]: type(df.iloc[::4,:])
Out[20]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Which selects *every four rows*, and returns a data-frame.

Comment: `df.iloc[::4,:]` still threw the same error.  Per your comment about changing how my data is saved -- I included how my data is saved from the python script.  Can you look it over and provide any feedback on how I can make it better?

Comment: @Gary yes, if you had read and understood what I was saying you would expect it to throw the error, since *that returns a dataframe*. You need to get a grip on what you are trying to do instead of just using randomly slicing and dicing your data-frame until it doesn't produce errors, but it is representing junk!